# What should I do to connect mongoose 5.8 with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose. 5.8.2 and following a tutorial where the person is running mongoose on v3.5. I know there has been changes like useNewUrlParser has been deprecated and instead we use useUnifiedTopology but the problem is that whenever I use useUnifiedTopology then I get the error that it has been deprecated. Please have a look below and let me know what am I doing wrong

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api', {
    useUnifiedToplogy: true,
    useCreateIndex: true

});

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    }
})

const me = new User({
    name: 'Lallan',
    age: '27'
})

me.save().then(() => {
    console.log('Done')
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error)
})
```

and the following is the error and I'm not able to connect mongoose with mongodb

```
the options [useUnifiedToplogy] is not supported
(node:6573) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:6573) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

What should I do to connect mongoose with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

The most default connection will be to just `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`. You can use `createConnection()`(for multiple pools) as well as `connect()`(single pool).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) a basic example will be:

> ```
> //Import the mongoose module
> var mongoose = require('mongoose');
>
> //Set up default mongoose connection
> var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
> mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true });
>
> //Get the default connection
> var db = mongoose.connection;
>
> //Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
> db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
> ```

Also,

> If you need to create additional connections you can use
>   `mongoose.createConnection()`. This takes the same form of database URI
>   (with host, database, port, options etc.) as connect() and returns a
>   Connection object.

like,

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database', opts);
```

Comment: Still showing this error

(node:7030) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Comment: sorry for this late comment, just add `useUnifiedToplogy: true` with the option. it will not show anymore warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try giving it this way,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let db_uri = "'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"

mongoose.connect(db_uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology : true
});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```